# Simple encrypt/decrypt of utf-8 strings in php5 with secret key

Tags: php, utf-8, encryption, multibyte

Could somebody advice me on subject "Simple encrypt/decrypt of utf-8 strings in php5 with secret key" ? Some advice on independant libraries? 
(no dependancy on 32/64bit machines).

```
$encryptedTextUTF8 = simpleEncrypt($originalTextUTF8, $secret);
echo simpleDecrypt($encryptedTextUTF8, $secret); // outputs $originalTextUTF8
```

Comment: Symmetric encryption is really hard to get right (i.e. secure). Make really sure that you can live with just a hash. If you need actual symmetric encryption, have a look at the mcrypt module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the mcrypt extension: http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php
Something like the following could be feasible:

```
$pass      = 'password_string_to_be_encrypted';
$string    = 'password_string_to_be_decrypted';
$salt      = 'your_salt';
$pepper    = 'your_extra_salt';
$encrypted = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $salt . $pass . $pepper ), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $salt . $pass . $pepper ))));
$decrypted = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($salt . $pass . $pepper), base64_decode( $string ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $salt . $pass . $pepper))), "\0");
```

edit: Proven wrong, I suggest to remove the md5 part of the encryption. As to what is better, I do not know yet, but I'll try to come update my post when I've had sufficient time investigating.. sorry! :)

Comment: And like stated above, copypasting this directly into production is a no no -- but it should be something to get you started and understand how it's done.

Comment: md5ing the password and/or initialization vector *significantly reduces the possible range of bytes used*, thus decreasing available entropy, thus making it much easier to crack.  Further, using an md5 of something derived from the password as the IV could also further reduce security.

Comment: I was a bit uncertain whether you were right, and after spending a good hour of investigating, you were right. I'll patch my own encryption functions accordingly now, thanks a lot! I just took it as a given that md5 was good.. scary how crap it actually is! :o

Answer (score 1):

PHP strings don't know (or care) what their character encoding is.  They're just a collection of bytes.  This allows you to entirely not worry about UTF-8 here.

Because you're asking for symmetric key encryption, you'll probably want to use [the mcrypt extension](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php).  It has [a wide variety of cyphers](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) available, including AES ("Rijndael").  Mcrypt itself doesn't care whether or not it's on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine.

I'm not going to provide example code, because using encryption requires some non-trivial knowledge that I'm not sure I can properly explain to you *in code alone*, and copy-paste of encryption code is a bad, bad idea.

[Understanding how block cypher modes of operation work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) will help you pick the proper mode for what you're doing.  This understanding will also be necessary if you wish to have programs developed in other languages work with your encrypted data, as they'll use different default cipher modes and different [padding schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29).